# Etymology of the word "Kvater"

Tags: words, etymology, brit-milah, yiddish

What is the etymology of the word "Kvater"? Kvater is what we call the person that carries the baby boy into a Bris.

Comment: Quarterback? Holds the baby like like a football...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Aruch HaShulchan Yoreh De'ah 265:35](https://www.sefaria.org/Arukh_HaShulchan%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.265.35?lang=bi):

> וקורין לזה קוואט"ר. ויראה לי שזהו מלשון "קטורת", דאמרינן בכריתות (כריתות ו ב): מה לשון "קטורת"? דבר שקוטר ועולה. ופירש רש"י: קוטר – שמתמר ועולה כמקל, עיין שם. וכיון שנתבאר שהמילה היא כקטורת, לכן נקרא זה שמקרב התינוק אל המילה, שמקרבו להקטרת. ועל פי שינוי הלשונות נתחלף בין "קוטר" בחד וי"ו לקוואט"ר בשני ווי"ן.‏
>
> We call him *kvatter*.
>
> It seems to me that this is related to the word *ketoret* (incense), as we say in Keritot, "What is the meaning of *ketoret*? Something which is *koter* and rises." Rashi explains: "*Koter* - that it collects in a cloud and rises like a stick". See there.
>
> As we have explained, *milah* is like *ketoret*, therefore the one who brings the child to the *milah* is called this [*koter*] because he brings him to the *ketoret*.
>
> And through the evolution of language, the word changed from *koter* with one *vav* to *kvatter* with two *vavin*.

Comment: All my respect to R' Epstein, but it's absolutely implausible that this is the etimology...

Comment: @Kazibácsi So he made up an etymology that makes no sense?

Comment: @Shababnik I don't know who made it up, but it is not reasonable linguistically https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%95%D7%90%D6%B7%D7%98%D7%A2%D7%A8

Comment: @Kazibácsi what you're saying does make sense. Especially since סנדק means Godfather.

Answer (score 11):

[According to this article](http://www.forward.com/articles/423/), it is from the Medieval German word, Gottvater (godfather).

Comment: Wikipedia agrees with this one (though disagrees on the spelling... "Kvater is etymologically derived from the German Gevatter ("godfather")." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godparent#Judaism ... It is much less of a jump from Gevatter to kvater than it would be from Gottvater to kvater.

Comment: @Seanja Gevatter could be the bridge between the two.

Answer (score 5):

[This post](http://ottmall.com/mj_ht_arch/v48/mj_v48i66.html#CSE) claims that it comes from "kavod tir" (Yiddish: honor at the door), although I haven't found this in his cited source, Ohel Rachel by R. Chaim Liberman.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have this sefer; but [Wikipedia](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%A0%D7%93%D7%A7_(%D7%99%D7%94%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA)) quotes the sefer otzar taamei minhagim which explains that it might be a misconstrued form of the Hebrew word like כ. And the German פאטער:

> הואיל והוא בא בשליחות האב להביא את הילד למילה ו"שלוחו של אדם כמותו" (ברכות לד) לכן הוא נקרא "כאבא" – כפאטר בלעז [...]
> י"א שמקור השם מלשון קטורת. מאחר שהוקשה מילה לקטורת, לכן נקרא מגיש התינוק למילה קוטר, כפי שאמרו (כריתות ו) מה לשון קטורת דבר שקוטר ועולה. ומ"קוטר" בוא"ו אחד השתנה ל"קווטר" בשני וא"וין.